# Upperbound on the following logarithmic function with matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality

I am trying to find an upperbound the expression below with a function $f$ that is a function of the identity matrix

$$\log(1+\mathbf{h}^* \mathbf{\Sigma}  \mathbf{h}) \leq  f( {\bf I},{\bf h })$$

$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1-|\rho_1|^2 & \rho_3 - \rho_1 \rho_2^* \\
\rho_3^* - \rho_1^*\rho_2 & 1-|\rho_2|^2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
$$|\rho_i |\leq 1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall i =[1:3]$$

where ${\bf h} $ is a column vector with complex entries

Does anyone have any idea if this possible, my aim is to get rid of $\Sigma$?

Thanks, appreciate any ideas

Comment: I've had an answer to this one posted for a couple days, I take it from your bounty comment that wikipedia is not a "credible source"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your matrix is Hermitian, its eigenvalues are real.  Furthermore, they are less than or equal to $2$ for all such $\Sigma$ (see [Gershgorin's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem)).  Alternatively, you can observe that the modulus of each entry is bound by 2, so the matrix can at most magnify a vector by that.

Let $a_i$ be the projection of $h$ on the $i$th eigenvector.
Now we know that $h^*\Sigma h = \langle \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i e_i, \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i \lambda_i e_i \rangle \leq 2 \langle \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i e_i, \sum_{i=1}^2 a_i e_i\rangle = 2|h|^2$.

Due to this bound and since $\log$ is increasing,
$$\log(1 + h^*\Sigma h) \leq \log(1 + 2|h|^2)$$

That is your function $f(\textbf{I},\textbf{h})$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24166/discussion-on-answer-by-muaddib-upperbound-on-the-following-logarithmic-function).